# jqueryUI autocomplete with extra data?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Using [jQueryUI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source)

I'd like to attach some other data onto a results list from the box. For instance, my data set might look like:

```
[
    {
        "name": "John's wild bacon emporium",
        "code": "BACON"
    },
    {
        "name": "Jill and Jack's well",
        "code": "WELL"
    },
    {
        "name": "Herp and derp",
        "code": "HD"
    }
]
```

But the jQueryUI docs say it wants a flat array of strings.

Users are going to search by name, never the code (lets pretend). More importantly, I want to be able to access what that code is when looking at `select: function(event, ui) {/*...*/}`, be it through the data-xxx, or some other voodoo. I'd like to avoid using a second list to match up strings against label contents (lets pretend we can have duplicate names somehow and users will never get confused), I just want to glue the code data onto the name label.

A question like this was [asked in 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372434/jquery-autocomplete-how-to-handle-extra-data), but since then the plugin doesn't have `.result()` anymore.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> But the jQueryUI docs say it wants a
>   flat array of strings.

[Actually](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/):

> The local data can be a **simple Array**
>   of Strings, or it contains **Objects** for
>   each item in the array, with either a
>   **label** or **value** property or both.

So as long as your data has *at least* a `value` property for each object in the array, the widget can handle it:

```
[
    {
        "name": "John's wild bacon emporium",
        "code": "BACON",
        "value": "Bacon",
    },
    {
        "name": "Jill and Jack's well",
        "code": "WELL"
        "value": "Well"
    },
    {
        "name": "Herp and derp",
        "code": "HD",
        "value": "Herp"
    }
]
```

The user's query will be matched against the `value` property of each object (notice that label is not required; only specify it if you want to show something different in the list of autocomplete options than the `value`).

You can access the extra data about the item inside the `select` event handler:

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    alert(ui.item.code); // Access the item's "code" property.
}
```

Hope that helps. Here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/vR3QH/. I removed the `name` property and am just using the `value` property instead. Every time an item is selected, `input` elements are updated with values of properties belonging to the selected item.

Comment: Thanks! Double thanks for the jsfiddle! Lesson learned today: Slow down and read things you thought you knew because you scanned them.

Comment: @user257493: No problem! They really should make the `source` option more visible in the documentation.

Comment: The "name" attributes are misleading here, as the correct key is "label".

Comment: @lav That's true